# Flipping a 3D text around its Y axis SharpGL

Tags: c#, opengl

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly MainViewModel _mainViewModel;
    private float _rotation;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
        DataContext = _mainViewModel;
    }
    private void OpenGLControl_OpenGLInitialized(object sender, OpenGLEventArgs args)
    {
        OpenGL gl = args.OpenGL;
        gl.Enable(OpenGL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.ShadeModel(OpenGL.GL_SMOOTH);
    }

    private void OpenGLControl_OpenGLDraw(object sender, OpenGLEventArgs args)
    {
        OpenGL gl = args.OpenGL;

        // Clear The Screen And The Depth Buffer
        gl.Clear(OpenGL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | OpenGL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Move Left And Into The Screen
        gl.LoadIdentity();
        gl.Translate(0.0f, 0.0f, _mainViewModel.Zoom);

        if (_mainViewModel.Rotate)
        {
            gl.Rotate(_rotation, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
        }

        gl.Color(_mainViewModel.RgbColors[0], _mainViewModel.RgbColors[1], _mainViewModel.RgbColors[2]);

        gl.DrawText3D("Mazor", (float) 30.0, (float) 1.0, (float) 0.5, "Mazor");

        _rotation += 3.0f;
        gl.Flush();
    }
}
```

I would like to flip the 3D text I have around y axis, I am able to do so, 
However I want the word "Mazor" to flip around the middle of the word, and not around the left side of the word.

if you run the code you can see the rotation occurs around the M letter, where as I would like to change the y axis to be where the Z letter is.
Can you please help ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to first translate the modelview matrix so that the middle of the word is at the origin, do your rotation, and then translate it back to its previous position. So something like this:

```
    if (_mainViewModel.Rotate)
    {
        gl.Translate(0.0, 0.0, -(_mainViewModel.zoom + textWidth / 2.0));
        gl.Rotate(_rotation, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.Translate(0.0, 0.0, _mainViewModel.zoom + textWidth / 2.0);
    }
```

This assumes that the width of the text is stored in a variable named `textWidth`.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to know the textWidth?

Comment: `gl.DrawText3D()` is not an OpenGL call, so you'll have to look up the documentation for whatever that is to get the text width.